# FQL multiquery does not always work

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql, fql.multiquery

I have a strange problem with a FQL multiquery

This is my query:

```
NSString *query =
        @"{"
        @"\"events_info\":\"SELECT name, description, pic_small, pic_big, eid, venue, location, start_time, end_time, timezone, update_time, not_replied_count, privacy, has_profile_pic, version, can_invite_friends, is_date_only, hide_guest_list, host, creator, all_members_count, attending_count, not_replied_count , declined_count, pic_cover FROM event WHERE eid IN (SELECT eid FROM event_member WHERE uid IN (SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1 = me()) AND start_time > '2013-03-03T00:23:00' OR uid = me())\","
        @"\"event_venue\":\"SELECT name, type,page_id, location FROM page WHERE page_id IN (SELECT venue.id FROM #events_info)\","
        @"\"event_creator\":\"SELECT name, page_id, type FROM page WHERE page_id IN (SELECT creator.id FROM #events_info)\""
        @"}";
```

This query sometimes does not work... I do not understand what's wrong.
When not working, if I delete the third query (`event_creator`) everything works.

**ERROR:**

```
Error Domain=com.facebook.sdk Code=5 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (com.facebook.sdk error 5.)" UserInfo=0xaab6c50 {com.facebook.sdk:ParsedJSONResponseKey={
    body =     {
        "error_code" = 1;
        "error_msg" = "An unknown error occurred";
    };
    code = 500;
}, com.facebook.sdk:HTTPStatusCode=500}
```

Comment: What kind of message does facebook return when your query fails?

Comment: @Darvex I edited the post with the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the **first** query, you want to retrieve:

- the page of the event creator,
- the page of the venue to this event.

What you get looks like:

```
{
    "venue": {
        "id": 421431217881031
    }, 
    "creator": 844413621
},
```

In the **second** query you get the information of the venue's page as such: `WHERE page_id IN (SELECT venue.id FROM #events_info)`. This is very well done because you indeed need to look after the `ID` of the venue *into* the `venue` array.

In the **third** query, `creator` is not an array anymore! It represents a page `ID` (or a user's, but that's not a problem because they are going to be filtered). In that case, you can get the `ID` directly:

`WHERE page_id IN (SELECT creator FROM #events_info)`

instead of

`WHERE page_id IN (SELECT creator.id FROM #events_info)`.

Comment: your response probably is correct but it not resolve the problem... sometime the query not work also with your modify..

Comment: That's because your query times out without any doubt. You are asking for too much information. Try to lower the time range for the events you request: `AND start_time > '2013-03-03T00:23:00' AND start_time < '2013-03-04T00:23:00'`.

Comment: yes..I tried and I have response...
So, Can I add LIMIT operator in my query to avoid this?

Comment: exactly! Good idea. `LIMIT 10` for example, at the end of the first query. Also, `OFFSET` will start at 0, and will be incremented by 10 each time. `LIMIT 10 OFFSET 0`, `LIMIT 10 OFFSET 10`, `LIMIT 10 OFFSET 20` and so on...